# Anymote to invoke keyevents on Google TV itself

Tags: android, google-tv

Hi guys i have a multipart question. First of all how would it be possible to invoke a keyevent on in a app on the google tv itself? For example i would like to have a button in my app that can invoke the live tv keyevent? I know it is possible because the Ableremote app on the market does this it have a client and server app. I appreciate any help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all how would it be possible to invoke a keyevent on in a app on the google tv itself? For example i would like to have a button in my app that can invoke the live tv keyevent?

This is not possible in standard Android.

> I know it is possible because the Ableremote app on the market does this it have a client and server app.

They are using the [remote protocol](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/), which AFAIK cannot be run on the Google TV device itself, but only from apps on other Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question, it is possible to launch live TV on click on a button:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tv://passthrough"));
ImageButton tvButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.tv_button);
tvButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```